# Mac test scenarios

Tags: macos, cocoa, appstore-approval, mac-app-store

Recently I submitted an app to Mac app store. It got rejected for a very silly reason stated,

> Menu Bar Extra is invisible when in Dark Mode on Mac OS X 10.10.

This was my first submission, hence wasnt aware of this test case.
Is there any source / blog where I can get this basic test cases, which would be required for every mac application to satisfy. Some thing which would cover all the test cases which apple undergo.

Also this is the only reason apple has responded me with, so shall I safely assume that apple has tested all other features and every thing is working fines except the one mentioned above.

How many times can I submit the same app (assuming continuous rejections) before apple looses their patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no list of test cases beyond the submission guidelines and everything implicit and explicit in the HIG and API docs.

It's worthy of a radar though. File it. 
It would be great to have automated test cases or at least guidance based on functionality used.